# Apache-spark: How to pass Iterable[String] as parameter in a function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have used groupByKey on key value pair i got output of type [(String, Iterable[String])]

I am calling a function on map transformation on above output but i am getting error on function declaraion.

```
def getStr (uid : String, locations : Array[]) : String = {
   return "test"
}
```

I don't know how to use Iterable[String] as function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If RDD has type `RDD[(String, Iterable[String])]`, to map its records you'll need a function receiving a *single* argument with the same type of the RDD's records, i.e.:

```
def getStr(record: (String, Iterable[String])): String = { "test" }
```

If you're wondering what can be done with an `Iterable` - see [docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/trait-iterable.html).

Sometimes the simplest approach (though not necessarily best performing) is to convert it to a list, and then you get a richer API, e.g. to get the first item of the iterator, or a default if it's empty:

```
def getStr(record: (String, Iterable[String])): String = record match { 
  case (s, iter) => iter.toList.headOption.getOrElse("UNKNOWN") 
}
```

Comment: How would we know if the OP needs to use `toList` on the iterable if we don't know what he wants to do with it? I mean, in case `Iterable[String]` is large, we have an unnecessary O(n) operation, maybe for no reason.

Comment: All true - I'm assuming the OP was mostly concerned about the signature of `getStr`, the rest is merely an _example_ for an implementation to see how such a signature can be used, including the performance disclaimer... I admit `toList` might be a dangerous tip here, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, How can i access record[String] and record[Iterable] in getStr function

Comment: The example shows exactly that - using pattern matching, `record` is matched to a `(s, iter)` pattern, where `s` would be the String and `iter` would be the Iterable. On the right-hand-side of the `=>` in the case clause, you can use these variables as you like.

Comment: Another option would be to use `record._1` for the left item (the String) and `record._2` for the right item (the Iterable) in the tuple.